# How can i feed more images into a caffe model?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a trained caffe model with next files:

```
deploy.prototxt 
mean_value.txt
model.caffemodel
```

How do i feed more images into it to increase its accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

Retraining with more images to increase accuracy

Try finetuning with your caffemodel

Comment: isnt there a way i can feed it images one by one? I mean i get one image every minute or so, and feed it immediately to the model.